# Best way to invite fb friends to join to my android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After research on facebook developer website I found that an app without Canvas can only use Share Dialog to invite someone who don't have the app installed on the phone. The default Share Dialog it's not the best way to invite friends because you only can tag someone and put a link inside the request. Invited users will receive a notification in that he is tagged in --- by ---,  and this is posted on user wall that make the "invitation" . I don't no if it's a method to custom this to looks like a game invite request. I saw apps that send invitations to users that is only received at fb app at phone and at website isn't dispalyed the notification. This is the method that I like to use, but I don't know how to make it with the new fb api version.
However it's a method to send invites in an native way? In which conditions can I use Request Dialog for my android app? Can I make a fake Canvas Fb app and after user Request Dialog? It's another method to view a list with all fb friends (include the users that don't use the app), select them and send invitations?

Have someone a idea how to make a pretty invite request?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use a fake canvas app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app explain it very clearly

Comment: I read this but with Share Dialog I was able only to make a post in that I put a link with my app and tag a list of friends. I like to make a request to invite not to tag someone

Comment: You can't. That is what the documentation say

Comment: I saw apps that send invite request in that you only select friends that you link to invite and he receive this at newsfeed. I don't no if this was possible only in older versions of api or uses another method, not with share dialog or message

Comment: They are must be using API v1.0 so they will stop doing that at 4/30/2015

Answer (score 0):

Use webDialog of facebook to send invites to any of your friends.

```
 WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
LoginActivity.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
   @Override
 public void onComplete(Bundle values,
   FacebookException error) {
}
}
```

You will get an easy example [here](http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/03/send-application-invites-to-facebook.html)